# Determine if string is "affirmative"?

Tags: python

I'd like to use Python 3's `input()` function to ask the user a yes or no question. For example:

```
affirmative = ["", "y", "yes"]
x = input("Continue? [Y/n] ").lower()
if x in affirmative:
    # Do something
else:
    print("Canceled")
```

Is there a certain list I should be using for "affirmative" answers? I know Python has things like `string.uppercase` and `string.lowercase` for pre-determined lists of variables. Is there a list of answers that should be considered a "yes" answer?

Comment: well, for one, I wouldn't say that a blank string is affirmative...

Comment: Since you are asking the user to enter `Y` (the default) or `n`, I think checking for the first letter is sufficient.

Comment: @roippi it's like `apt-get`, it assumes you want to do what you requested, but confirms it first

Comment: `if input(...).lower()[:1] in "y"` covers the empty case and all responses starting with "y" or "Y".

Comment: But, to answer your question ;-), no - there is no standard list of affirmative responses.

Answer (score 6):

Python's distutils has `strtobool` which might work for you. [Documentation Link](http://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=distutils.util#distutils.util.strtobool).

> **distutils.util.strtobool(val)**
>
> Convert a string representation of truth to true (1) or false (0).
>
> - True values are: **y**, **yes**, **t**, **true**, **on**, **1**.
> - False values are: **n**, **no**, **f**, **false**, **off**, **0**.
> - Raises ValueError otherwise.

But this doesn't exactly fit with the style you're currently hoping for.

Comment: Ya, but ... when the prompt **says** "Y/n", a user entering (e.g.) "True" is just confused :-(

Comment: @TimPeters: I agree. I think the proper solution is to homebrew a set of acceptable responses.

Answer (score 1):

I have a better idea:  accept anything starting with "yYnN", and an empty string if you must.  Complain about anything else and ask again.  Users will get used to that very quickly.

"There should be one- and preferably only one -obvious way to do it" :-)

Comment: That's catchy, someone should write that down.

Answer (score 0):

Considering any answers (which also could be multiple) affirmative or negative is all up to you. You can either create an array of potential user answers (as you've already shown) or you can simply tell the user the input was wrong and alert with a message like "please answer yes or no".

Also mostly used affirmative messages would be `yes, y, true, t, 1`.